# Where can I ask about Computer Architecture?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

If I have problems that I can't solve, involving logic circuits and computer architecture, should I ask for help on Stack Overflow or on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: See [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in?rq=1) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you, I found my answer here with your link "... if your question depends on real-life languages/code/hardware/..., ask on Stack Overflow; if your question calls for abstract/mathematical models and reasoning, ask on Computer Science."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in?rq=1) I linked to in the comment:

> #### Computer Science
>
> For questions about computer science, as in the academic discipline. As a rule of thumb, if your question depends on real-life languages/code/hardware/..., ask on Stack Overflow; if your question calls for abstract/mathematical models and reasoning, ask on Computer Science. Algorithms expressed in pseudocode straddle the border.

Comment: I would rather have closed this question as a duplicate, but that isn't possible.